# Как правильно сохранять в pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

Как правильно записывать по 1 строчке?

вот мой код:

```
    data.append([colonka1, colonka2])
    print(data)
    header = ['colonka1', 'colonka2']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
    df.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf8')
```

Он записывает после тогда как полностью отработает весь скрипт и результат сохранит.
Как сделать так чтоб каждая строка записывалась и сохранялась или хотя бы по 10 строк, а то бывает код ломается и файл не сохраняется.
Подскажите как исправить код записи, чтоб во время работы скрипта всегда записывало в файл.scv?

Comment: По-моему, имеет место [Проблема XY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY). Возможно, вы не так применяете `pandas`. Из-за чего у вас "ломается код"? Может быть, поискать причину в этом?

Comment: Разобрался, занёс в цикл и стало нормально, записывает теперь каждую строчку. Нет код ломался у меня в другом не из-за Pandas. Спасибо за ответ.